# Sessions not storing while using them in view function django

Tags: django, python-3.x, session, django-forms

I want to store the username value in my browser sessions when i call the login function from view . I have tried the request.session syntax but it is not working and not storing the username in my sessions. I have confirmed that by going to the developer tools console.

VIEW FUNCTION

```
def login_submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        form = AppUserForm(request.POST)
        # form['my_field'].value()
        if AppUser.objects.filter(username=username, password=password).exists():

            request.session['username'] = username //I WANT TO SET THE SESSION HERE

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return login(request)
```

Comment: you mentioned "developer tools console", are you referring to "Session Storage" option in the browser?

Comment: yes i am referring to that only

Answer (score 0):

By default [Django-Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine) are stored in the Database (If other session engine is not provided). From the Docs:

> By default, Django **stores sessions in your database** (using the model django.contrib.sessions.models.Session). It is used to store data for one session. So if you close the Window/Tab, the session will expire.

So if you want to check user's session data, you can query the `django.contrib.sessions.models.Session` model.

This is the example of stored data in the model:

```
{
'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7f41e2908cf8>, 
'session_key': 'dmi7gfanckowzpikyihlt2a8696tuaka',
 'session_data': 'MDNkYTBlYzMxYTMyZWQ4YzMwZTk0ZY4EjTFmNjA5YWRjMTdiMTA1Nzp7Il9hdXRoX3VzZXJfaWQiOiIyIiwiX2F1dGhfdXNlcl9iYWNrZW5kIjoiZGphbmdvLmNvbnRyaWIuYXV0aC5iYWNrZW5kcy5Nb2RlbEJhY2tlbmQiLCJfYXV0aF91c2VyX2hhc2giOiI3NmQ5Y2I3ZTliNGIzYWExNDc2NmM1OTUxZDBlOWNmZmIxNTUyOGEzIn0=',
 'expire_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 10, 17, 20, 29, 768812,
 tzinfo=<UTC>)
}
```

I have called the `instance.__dict__` to get the data as dictionary.

The Session Storage you are referring is JavaScript's [`Window.sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). 
You can create Session Storage by: (snippet from Mozilla Docs)

```js
// Save data to sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value');

// Get saved data from sessionStorage
let data = sessionStorage.getItem('key');

// Remove saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.removeItem('key');

// Remove all saved data from sessionStorage
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Mozilla Docs on [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).

Comment: but how can i use javascript session storage in my django view function

Comment: get the value by `getItem`and pass it to django by ajax or you can set the data as cookie.

Comment: please can you help me with passing the getItem to django view by ajax maybe with some code

Comment: this should work, first set `sessionStorage.setItem('name', 'xyz')` and then `$.ajax({'url': '', 'type': 'POST', 'data': {'name': sessionStorage.getItem('name')}})`, this is working to me. Make sure to pass csrf token as well.